# Ctrl+Break on Apple keyboard

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I usually use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>break</kbd> to break the compilation in visual studio, and now my new apple (macbook pro) laptop does not have break key. Is there a shortcut that I can use on an apple laptop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if there is a <kbd>Fn</kbd> or some other key combo that duplicates a PC Break key, but you can assign any hot key you like to the Build.Cancel command from with Visual Studio. Just go to the Options dialog (available under the Tools drop menu), find the Build.Cancel command and assign a new shortcut for that command.

Answer (score 0):

yes ctrl+F14 (on mac full keyboard) :
Also you can use virtual keyboard for somethings in windows.
ctrl+F14 is interpreted by windows as ctrl+scrlLock, F14 on full mac keyboard is in the same position as scrl-lock key on windows full keyboard.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!